# Divergence of the series $\dfrac{x^n}{ \sin ( \pi \alpha n) }$ for $0<x<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

- $0<x<1$
- $u_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $u_0 \geq 2$
- $u_{n+1}= u_n ^{ u_n}$
- $\alpha= \sum_{n=0}^{+ \infty} \dfrac{1}{u_n}$
- **We want to prove that** the series  $\sum \dfrac{x^n}{ \sin ( \pi \alpha n) }$ diverges.

---

My attempt :
The sequence $(u_n)_n$ has been studied [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4104317/u-n1-u-nu-n)

$
\begin{align*}
\forall j, u_{j+1}&=u_j^{u_j} \in \mathbb{N} \\
\forall j, \forall k<j,  u_k &| u_j \\
\forall k, k <n, \dfrac{u_n}{u_k} &\in  \mathbb{N} \\
\forall n, u_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{u_k} &\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align*}
$

$
\begin{align*}
\sin( u_n \pi \alpha) &= \sin( u_n \pi \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{u_n} + u_n \pi \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_n} ) \\
\sin( u_n \pi \alpha)&= \sin( u_n \pi \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_n}     ) \\
 |\sin( u_n \pi \alpha)|  & \leq  | u_n \pi \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_n}  |    \\
 |\sin( u_n \pi \alpha)|  & \leq   u_n \pi \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_n}    \\
& \leq\dfrac{ \pi C }{  u_n^{u_n -1}  } \\
\end{align*}
$

$C$ is an intercept, that does not depend on $n$.

$$\dfrac{x^{u_n} }{ |\sin( u_n \pi \alpha)|    } \geq \dfrac{1}{ \pi C } x^{u_n} u_n^{u_n -1} (\star) $$

We expect to get the divergence from this last inequality called ($\star$). $u_n \to \infty$

We can prove that $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$
Assume that $\alpha= \dfrac{p}{q}$ where $p,q \in \mathbb{Q}$
then

$
\begin{align*}
u_n \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{u_k} &\in \mathbb{N} \\
\alpha=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_k} &\in \mathbb{N}\\
q u_n \sum_{k=n1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_k} &\in \mathbb{N} \\
q u_n \sum_{k=n1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{u_k} &\to 0
\end{align*}
$

It is a contradiction so $\alpha \not \in \mathbb{Q}$

We get the divergence from $\star$ because $u_n > n+1$

Comment: So, assuming your calculations are correct, you showed that there is $\alpha$ for which the series converges. The more interesting question is for which $\alpha$ the series converges. Obviously, one has to look at non-rational values (which brings another question - how do you know that the $\alpha$ for which you do calculations is irrational?)

Comment: I have added a proof for $\alpha$ irrationnal. How do we prove the divergence from $\star$ ?

Comment: It depends on what $\pi\cdot\alpha$ is, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722526/let-q-in-mathbb-c-q-1-and-qn-neq-1-forall-n-in-mathbb-n-show/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $\alpha$ is irrational, then the sequence given by $z_n=e^{i\pi\alpha n}$ is dense in $\mathbb{S}^1$ ([irrational rotations are transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrational_rotation)). So, there is a subsequence $n'$ along which $z_n\rightarrow e^{ -i\pi\alpha}=(\cos\pi\alpha,-\sin\pi\alpha)$. From
$$
\frac{|\sin(\pi\alpha n)|}{|\sin(\pi\alpha (n+1))|}=\frac{|\sin\pi\alpha n|}{|\sin(\pi\alpha n)\cos(\pi \alpha)+\sin(\pi\alpha)\cos(\pi\alpha n)|}=\frac{1}{|\cos(\pi\alpha)+\sin(\pi\alpha)\cot(\pi\alpha n)\big|}
$$
we have that along the subsequence $n'$, $\frac{|\sin\pi\alpha n|}{|\sin(\pi\alpha(n+1))|}\rightarrow\infty$.
Thus,
$$ \infty =\limsup_n\frac{|\sin(\pi\alpha n)|}{|\sin(\pi\alpha (n+1))|}\leq \limsup_n \sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{|\sin(\pi\alpha n)|}}$$
This means that the  radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{z^n}{\sin\pi\alpha  n}$ is $0$.